# Can we get the elements attached inside unclickable link using selenium python?

Tags: javascript, selenium, web-scraping

[image]

[image]

The first pic , pointing 2:40 PM is a element which had seat layout previously, but due filling of seats completely they have muted this link ,

The second pic pointing 5:20 is a link is clickable link and send us to page, which has the seat layout of the that current screen and timing for that theater

I dont have really info about how the links work at back end,but i do know is if we give links at href ,it will naviagate to the next page,

I want the information about the seat layout at 2:40 pm, how can i get that using the elements available in that div,does the element have the javascrift stored anywhere else, using selenium python

Sorry my poor technical word usage, I dont have prior experience in web development, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is to find out if you can click on the link and proceed further with booking, then you can use the class property of the links.

[seat filling link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zToRW.png)

[seat sold out link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWxDm.png)

Basically, you can get all links and iterate through those and get the class attribute value and check if you have the value 'enabled' in it. If yes, those are clickable links.

If you only want to find out clickable links then you can filter those links using XPath itself. You can try something like the one below.

```
//a[contains(@class,'enabled')]
```

This is just an example, you may have to further improve this meet you exact requirement.

If this is not what you are looking for, please add more details on what exactly is you requirement.

Comment: Thanks Manu for the suggestions but, here the situation , if the click the green or orange colored time links ,we will get the seat layout for the show, but i want the seat layout for the greyed out links , but in the greyed out ones the href element has been removed, so i cant get the pagelayout for unclickable links, how can get the data without clicking

Comment: @PuneethGP I am not sure if it is possible to get what you are asking for (at least using selenium). I think the website has blocked the end users from getting any data from the greyed-out ones. Since the seats for those greyed-out timings are already sold out, I don't think the website in any way will allow you to view the seat layout for it.